# How to print a HttpResponse in a while loop and then append onto it for each loop?

Tags: python, django, view, httpresponse

Okay so I have this view:

```
def fight(request):
    monster = Monster.objects.get(pk=request.POST['monster'])
    user = Profile.objects.get(pk=2)
    while monster.health > 0 and user.health > 0:
        monsterattack = random.randint(monster.minattack, monster.maxattack)
        userattack = random.randint(user.attack*.75, user.attack*1.5)
        user.health = user.health - monsterattack
        monster.health = monster.health - userattack
        HttpResponse('Player attacked for: %s\n Monster attacked for: %s\n' % (userattack, monsterattack))
    return HttpResponse('You are fighting %s\n Player Health: %s \n Monsters Health: %s' % (monster.name, user.health, monster.health))
```

I was wondering if there was a way that i could have the first HttpResponse print to the template every time it looped and then have the second while loop print after the while loop has finished.

Comment: You're not using any templates here. But you should be.

Comment: Yeah right now I’m just trying to see if i can get it to work bare bones are you saying that having a minimalistic template would be the only way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A view should return a single `HTTPResponse`. It doesn't make sense to add multiple `HttpResponse` objects together.

You could concatenate strings and return a single res

```
def fight(request):
    out = ""
    while monster.health > 0 and user.health > 0:
        out += 'Player attacked for: %s\n Monster attacked for: %s\n' % (userattack, monsterattack)
    out += 'You are fighting %s\n Player Health: %s \n Monsters Health: %s' % (monster.name, user.health, monster.health)
    return HttpResponse(out)
```

Another common pattern is to generate a list of strings, then join them at the end. This can be faster than concatenating strings, although I'm not sure you'll see any noticeable difference in this case:

```
def fight(request):
    out = []
    while monster.health > 0 and user.health > 0:
        out.append('Player attacked for: %s\n Monster attacked for: %s' % (userattack, monsterattack))
    out.append('You are fighting %s\n Player Health: %s \n Monsters Health: %s' % (monster.name, user.health, monster.health)
    return HttpResponse("\n".join(out))
```

Answer (score 0):

A view only returns one single response. What you want will require either ajax polling (simple but not very efficient) or websockets (more complex - look at django-channels for a how to in Django - but probably more efficient for your kind of app).